# IntelliJ/PhpStorm inline @var with magic fields

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am trying to define with a PHPDoc **inline @var** a magic field variable to set the correct type but the IDE is not auto-completing anything.

It is showing "Field accessed via magic method". I tried to remove it from the **Inspections** settings but then the warning is not showed and still it is not auto-completing.

I have tried different ways without success:

```php
/** @var \NameSpace\SomeClass $this->field */
$this->field->someMethod(); // Not auto-completing

/** @var \NameSpace\SomeClass $this::field */
$this->field->someMethod(); // Not auto-completing
```

For other hand if I define a new variable it will work:

```php
$field = $this->field;

/** @var \NameSpace\SomeClass $field */
$field->someMethod(); // Auto-completing correctly
```

Somebody knows how to do it to work the auto-completing feature without define a new variable? Is it possible?

UPDATE: I cannot use the @property attribute because $field is not always the same class in the main class.

Comment: New variable is your best option.  Its usage stays local, so it's not much of a burden.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be done via `@property` tag at class-level PHPDoc comment.

```
/**
 * My special class
 *
 * @property \NameSpace\SomeClass $field Optional my magical variable description
 */
class MySpecialClass {
....
```

https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html

---

```
/** @var \NameSpace\SomeClass $this->field */
```

This will never work -- you cannot provide typehint for 2nd level variable/element (`$this->field`) using inline `@var`. If anything: only first level entities can be typehinted.

Comment: My problem is $field is not always the same class. So then It is not possible without define a new $var. Thank you.

Comment: Re-declare it in current class (you are using `$this` to access it, so it can be done). If it's accessed from some another class (`$something->field`) .. then only by using intermediate variable (assign to a local variable which you can typehint).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to provide typehint for 2nd level variable/element ($this->field) using inline `@var` ([thank to @LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671091/2389232)).

So a possible solution would be set the `@property` with all classes using in the main class:

```
/**
 * My special class
 *
 * @property \NameSpace\SomeClass|OtherSomeClass|OneMore $field
 */
class MySpecialClass {
```

By this way the magic field `$field` would be auto-completing with all method of all classes defined.

Comment: *"\NameSpace\SomeClass|OtherSomeClass|OneMore $field"* Why this way? Why you need to list ALL possible cases here? What you will be doing tomorrow if you will need to add another 5 more classes -- list them here again? That's just bad approach overall (remember -- IDE will combine methods/fields from all these classes .. which may lead to very unexpected results and editor slow downs)

Comment: Sure ... if the list will be 2-3 classes long only -- it will work good enough. But if it will be a long list of classes .. or they will have the same methods but with different signatures .. -- not good at all (for both you and IDE). In such complex case it's better to use local/intermediate variable which you can easily typehint. If you are accessing such field very often and tired (do not want to) typehinting it all the time -- better introduce special local method `getField()` (in each class) that will return proper typehint and use it.